# Can single ESXi host make use of two separete iSCSI box?

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, truenas

I have problem with using multiply iSCSI targets with single ESXi host (in my case they are two FreeNAS hosts, but I suspect that this problem will occur with any two iSCSI box of that same type/model). If I configure two FreeNAS hosts as iSCSI targets (say iSCSI A and iSCSI B), then I can use both of them with my ESXi host, but only one at a time (i.e only iSCSI A or only iSCSI B, but not both of them simultaneously). If I try to add second iSCSI target to my iSCSI adapter (of course it has unique iqn name), then in a details pane of this adapter (it is iSCSI software adapter), I see that total number of paths has increased accordingly, but not total number of devices (so I can't use it as another storage).

What should I do? It is impossible to attach two iSCSI targets to single adapter?
I'm using free version of ESXi 4.1. Maybe it is an limitation of free version?

Thanks in advance for any sugestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have 128 different iSCSI LUNs per ESX4 host (might be 255 with 4.1 actually), any of which be from the same or multiple iSCSI sources, it's obviously a FreeNAS or implementation issue.

Comment: Yes, it may be possible, that this is FreeNAS problem. I have wrote, I'm suspect that this problem may occur also with other iSCSI arrays, because searching on this issue over Internet, I have found an suggestion (unfortunately, I can't find it now), that this problem is caused by iSCSI box incorrectly reporting it's type/brand/model as a serial number and this causes ESXi host to interpret target from second box as separate path to the same storage. (which is obviously wrong in this case).
It is possible to fix this?

Comment: No fix as far as I know, although I did just check and we have a number of ESXi hosts talking to 12 or more different NetApp hosts.

Comment: have you seen this?  http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/freenas/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=3318  It looks like you can adjust the freenas serial number.

Comment: Thanks Zoredache - your link was very helpful. Indeed configuring  unique value on FreeNAS for "Inquiry Serial" setting, solved my problem!

Thank you!